# Python idiom: List comprehension with limit of items

Tags: python, list-comprehension, idioms

I'm basically trying to do this (pseudo code, not valid python):

```
limit = 10
results = [xml_to_dict(artist) for artist in xml.findall('artist') while limit--]
```

So how could I code this in a concise and efficient way?
The XML file can contain anything between 0 and 50 artists, and I can't control how many to get at a time, and AFAIK, there's no XPATH expression to say something like "get me up to 10 nodes".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `xml` is an `ElementTree` object, the `findall()` method returns a list, so just slice that list:

```
limit = 10
limited_artists = xml.findall('artist')[:limit]
results = [xml_to_dict(artist) for artist in limited_artists]
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you using `lxml`? You could use XPath to limit the items in the query level, e.g.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> xml = etree.parse(StringIO('<foo><bar>1</bar><bar>2</bar><bar>4</bar><bar>8</bar></foo>'))
>>> [bar.text for bar in xml.xpath('bar[position()<=3]')]
['1', '2', '4']
```

---

You could also [use `itertools.islice` to limit any iterable](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), e.g.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> [bar.text for bar in islice(xml.iterfind('bar'), 3)]
['1', '2', '4']
>>> [bar.text for bar in islice(xml.iterfind('bar'), 5)]
['1', '2', '4', '8']
```

Comment: Do you think the XPath solution is faster than the slicing alternatives? I think Elements are lazy, but it might just be faster to not get the elements at all right? Not sure

Comment: @Infinity: I think `islice` is faster because XPath is more complicated. I haven't verified though. You need to benchmark it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone else who found this question because they were trying to limit items returned from an infinite generator:

```
from itertools import takewhile
ltd = takewhile(lambda x: x[0] < MY_LIMIT, enumerate( MY_INFINITE_GENERATOR ))
# ^ This is still an iterator. 
# If you want to materialize the items, e.g. in a list, do:
ltd_m = list( ltd )
# If you don't want the enumeration indices, you can strip them as usual:
ltd_no_enum = [ v for i,v in ltd_m ]
```

**EDIT:** Actually, [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is a much better option.

Answer (score 2):

```
limit = 10
limited_artists = [artist in xml.findall('artist')][:limit]
results = [xml_to_dict(artist) for limited_artists]
```

Answer (score 2):

This avoids the issues of slicing: it doesn't change the order of operations, and doesn't construct a new list, which can matter for large lists if you're filtering the list comprehension.

```
def first(it, count):
    it = iter(it)
    for i in xrange(0, count):
        yield next(it)
    raise StopIteration

print [i for i in first(range(1000), 5)]
```

It also works properly with generator expressions, where slicing will fall over due to memory use:

```
exp = (i for i in first(xrange(1000000000), 10000000))
for i in exp:
    print i
```

Comment: You don't really **need** to raise `StopIteration`.  Simply ending the function will do.